# App links does not work on android/ios default browsers?

Tags: facebook, url-scheme, deep-linking, applinks

I use following code to describe my links:

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="fb://page/$id">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.facebook.katana">
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Facebook">
<meta property="al:web:url" content="https://www.facebook.com/page/$id" />

<meta property="og:title" content="example page title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
```

Then, i use a href like `fb://page/$id`, and if app is installed - android default browser opens it like a charm. Otherwise i see "Page not found error" - it tries to open `fb` protocol anyway.

For ios i see message "Safari is unable to open this page"

How i can fix it?

Comment: Of course they don’t work in default browsers. You are not supposed to link to `fb://page/$id`, but use the actual HTTP URL of the page that those meta tags are embedded into. Then when someone clicks on that link and has the app in question installed, it will open the app, otherwise just that HTML page in the default browser.

Comment: @CBroe hm.. i can't understand how i should use it.. I tried several times, but it still does not work. Could you please provide an example as an answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why this deep link (applink), generated by facebook does not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333567/why-this-deep-link-applink-generated-by-facebook-does-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app-links information is used as *meta data* on your page. You can't *directly link to* App-links information.

The meta tags you have should be within the `<head>...</head>` of your page. Now, if an app-links compatible browser opens your page, it will detect the app-links information and can choose to give the option to the visitor to open your app instead.

It also happens to be that the format you refer to, `fb://page/$id` works on Android to open the Facebook app directly on your page. This is *not the case* for iOS. Actually, the functionality on Android isn't even officially supported. There is no official way to link to a Page (or anything, for that matter) directly in the App.

The App-Links structure is meant for you, as a developer, if you want users to be able to quickly open your app when they hit a web resource.